# Web3py didn't throw error(in Remix it did)

Tags: solidity, web3.py, ganache

The contracts I used:

[EtherDelta(DEX)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code)

[Freedomcoin(Token)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3f4055a1a7fe71a79c4b3c692c8264bff9e68a1e#code)

Here is my logic:

I use userA who deployed the two contracts to transfer 100Ether to userB, then userB invoke `depositToken`, however, as there is no `transferFrom` in the token's contract, it will go to fallback function:

```
  function() {
    throw;
  }
```

clearly it will throw, and that's exactly what happened in remix.

However, when I tested this in bytecode using web3py, the transaction was successful, `status` was `1`, and when I checked `balanceOf` in EtherDelta, it returned the true value. I don't know what's wrong. Is this something about web3py itself?

Here is my testing code, I used ganache-cli as testnet.

```
import json
from tqdm import trange
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider, WebsocketProvider

account1 = "0x827A309CCf3a92F259E2081240Da9A503495F101"
account2 = "0x52EDd47566812fb01BdAA58d58630fe95C757CdD"

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545',request_kwargs={'timeout':600}))

DexBinCode =""
#I'm omitting this as it's too long, but I'm sure that the deployment is successful.

dexDeploymentReceipt = w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from':account1,'value':0,'data':DexBinCode,'gas':100000000})
dexDeployHash = Web3.toHex(dexDeploymentReceipt)
truedexDeploymentReceipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(dexDeployHash)
dex_address = truedexDeploymentReceipt['contractAddress']

TokenBinCode = ""
# Same as the DEX contract

# Deploy token contract
try:
    tokenDeploymentReceipt = w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from':account1,'value':0,'data':TokenBinCode,'gas':100000000})
    tokenDeployHash = Web3.toHex(tokenDeploymentReceipt)
    truetokenDeploymentReceipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tokenDeployHash)
    token_address = truetokenDeploymentReceipt['contractAddress'] 

except:
    print('error1')


# Transfer 100 Ether from account1 to account2
try:
    setupBinCode = "0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000"+account2.replace('0x','')+"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064"
    setupTransferReceipt = w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from':account1,'to':token_address,'value':0,'data':setupBinCode,'gas':100000000})
    setupTransferHash = Web3.toHex(setupTransferReceipt)
    truesetupTransferReceipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(setupTransferHash)
except:
    print('error2')

# depositToken with account2
try:
    depositBinCode = "0x338b5dea000000000000000000000000"+token_address.replace('0x','')+"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f4"
    balanceBinCode = "0xf7888aec000000000000000000000000"+token_address.replace('0x','')+"000000000000000000000000"+account2.replace('0x','')
    depositReceipt = w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from':account2,'to':dex_address,'value':0,'data':depositBinCode,'gas':1000000000})
    depositHash = Web3.toHex(depositReceipt)
    trueDepositReceipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(depositHash)
    print(trueDepositReceipt)
    balance = w3.eth.call({'from':account2,'to':dex_address,'data':balanceBinCode})
    balance = Web3.toHex(balance)
    print(balance)
    if balance !='0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f4':
        print('error6')
except:
    print('error7')
```

The result of `trueDepositReceipt`:

```
AttributeDict({'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xeb4e17dc0025e2edb8c2108944b3d521b71c0d527acd97f1c2fbfddb331bd76f'), 'transactionIndex': 0, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0xc71c82f0d38fa2c8ac6dfce57068dd93b1420d23e4b6a99ecbe5d269d56298b6'), 'blockNumber': 80, 'from': '0x52EDd47566812fb01BdAA58d58630fe95C757CdD', 'to': '0x552044ff5ca9F9094754C1ed53fD84Ac182eCC9B', 'gasUsed': 50181, 'cumulativeGasUsed': 50181, 'contractAddress': None, 'logs': [AttributeDict({'logIndex': 0, 'transactionIndex': 0, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xeb4e17dc0025e2edb8c2108944b3d521b71c0d527acd97f1c2fbfddb331bd76f'), 'blockHash': HexBytes('0xc71c82f0d38fa2c8ac6dfce57068dd93b1420d23e4b6a99ecbe5d269d56298b6'), 'blockNumber': 80, 'address': '0x552044ff5ca9F9094754C1ed53fD84Ac182eCC9B', 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000080eff541e03059f920931ab7d93c942e2da3052700000000000000000000000052edd47566812fb01bdaa58d58630fe95c757cdd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f4', 'topics': [HexBytes('0xdcbc1c05240f31ff3ad067ef1ee35ce4997762752e3a095284754544f4c709d7')], 'type': 'mined'})], 'status': 1, 'logsBloom': HexBytes('0x00002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000')})
```

Please don't ask why I'm using bytecode... That's the request for my experiment. I can make sure that there are nothing wrong with the function signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the solidity version required by each contract the problem is that solc 0.4.9 used by the exchange has a bug that ignores the lack of value returned by `transferFrom`.

The exchange calls `transferFrom` from the token and it will revert if it returns false.

```
if (!Token(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)) throw;
```

But the token doesn't implement `transferFrom` so the token's fallback is called instead.

```
function () public payable {
    create(msg.sender);
}
```

Call to `create` succeed and returns **nothing**. But the exchange is expecting it to returns a bool.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}
```

The compiler's bug is that it uses the same memory buffer for both input and output parameters. So since the token returns nothing the input is evaluated as it was the output and for the exchange transferFrom returns **true**.

Compiling with a more recent solc version like 0.4.26 causes the call to revert because it uses the new opcodes RETURNDATASIZE to check that `transferFrom` has returned a bool.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!. In Remix I compile the contracts with 0.4.26, while in web3.py, I copied the creation bytecode from etherscan.io. So I guess the solc version is what caused the problem. Plus I seems to have mistakenly thought that when `transferFrom` is missing, the exchange's fallback will be called.

Comment: Can you please review [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90159/16043). The results are quite staggering IMO. Could this be a potential issue in the ecosystem, or did I get something wrong? Thanks.